# Check if session IP matches current IP - PHP

Tags: php, session

So I am checking an session IP against the current session. I have had a look at the the questions that may have my answer and none of them do.

What happens is that everytime I connect, I get 'Your IP doesn't match...'

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['ip']) and (strcmp($_SESSION['ip'], md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])))){
    echo "Your IP doesn't match your session, your IP: ". $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ." and your session IP: ". $_SESSION['ip']. ". <a href='/scripts/signout.php'>Click here to log out.</a>";
    die;
}
?>
```

I know to use HTTPX and will implement that after I fix this.
Also $_SESSION['ip'] is the md5(Current IP)

Comment: the md5 is not needed. and it isnt used consistently in the error msg. otherwise this kind of security can cause problem for valid usecases. (users behind proxy farm)

Comment: [`strcmp()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) returns 0 if two strings are equal, and zero is a falsy value, so if they match, your `if()` is not met. You need to test `!== 0`

Comment: There is no security benefits to tracking changes in IP for a session, and it's perfectly valid HTTP protocol for the IP to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are comparing session ip and md5 of ip address, so probably you need:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['ip']) and ((strcmp($_SESSION['ip'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) !== false))){
    echo "Your IP doesn't match your session, your IP: ". $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ." and your session IP: ". $_SESSION['ip']. ". <a href='/scripts/signout.php'>Click here to log out.</a>";
    die;
}
?>
```

Comment: `< 0`, not === false since you're copying from my faulty comment.

Answer (score 1):

[strcmp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) returns 0 if the strings match, and in php that will equal false, also you don't need the md5 call really.

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['ip']) && strcmp($_SESSION['ip'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) !== 0){
    echo "Your IP doesn't match your session, your IP: ". $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ." and your session IP: ". $_SESSION['ip']. ". <a href='/scripts/signout.php'>Click here to log out.</a>";
    die;
}
//or you can just go 

if(isset($_SESSION['ip']) && $_SESSION['ip'] !== $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
/// stuff
}
```